# Is there another way to transfer my village to a new device?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm getting rid of my current iPhone and change it for another iPhone 5s.

The thing is, the Game Center account I am using right now is not the same one my village is linked to, apparently. I have tried like four different Game Center accounts I might have used to no avail - the game keeps saying this is the wrong account.

Is there a way to tell what Game Center account is my village linked to currently?
Is there another way to transfer my village to the new device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, launch iTunes on the computer that your apps are stored on.
- Go to the Apps section of iTunes
- Right-click on `Clash of Clans`
- Click on `Get Info`
- Summary tab is where you would see 'Account Name.' It would be the
  apple ID that was used to purchase the app.

And it would probably be your gamecenter log-in as well that has your village saved.
Now so as to migrate from one device to another, simply go to `Settings` > `Game Center` > Click on the AppleID and voila.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If Sandman's solution is not working, there is another way to transfer an account to your new phone in-game.

- Go to `settings` (The gears on the bottom right)
- Click `Link device` under `Devices`
- Do the same on both your new phone and old phone
- On the OLD phone, click `This is the OLD DEVICE` and on the NEW phone, click `This is the NEW DEVICE`
- The game (old phone) will ask you what kind of device you want to link to, it might be possible (I have an android phone, so not sure) that if you click iOS device, it just suggests using your Game Center account, but if you click `I want to link to another device`, the game will provide you with a code that you can enter on the new device.

[image: DevicesMenu]

You can also use this strategy if you want to play on multiple devices and operating systems.

Hope this helps you or someone else.